# Generate random matrix, subject to equality constraints in R

Tags: r, simulation

I would like to generate an m by n random matrix, drawing from a uniform distribution for each element, subject to the constraint that each column must sum to one. I would also like to set the lower and upper bound constraints for each element.

Here is an example of the desired output (although not truly random), `mymatrix`:

```
dput(mymatrix)
structure(c(0.5, 1.59365940317881e-17, 1.89403184501105e-18, 
0.5, 8.96677015179615e-19, 1.7326456004408e-18, 0.499999858832886, 
0.499999838867718, 2.22092666609155e-08, 2.69754277003262e-07, 
2.78754819399023e-11, 1.0307976832927e-08, 0.42857144673908, 
0.499999904492316, 3.75555965298514e-08, 4.75046037021098e-08, 
3.3675224155978e-10, 0.0714285633716491, 0.357142848840934, 0.499999941890735, 
7.30974537548529e-08, 2.67022430383198e-08, 2.80475367418637e-10, 
0.142857109188155, 0.28571428969238, 0.499999933476062, 5.02671502622386e-08, 
3.11835918349941e-08, 1.10520352747797e-09, 0.214285694275616
), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))

colSums(mymatrix)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1

max(mymatrix)
#[1] 0.5
```

In this particular example, note that no element is less than zero or greater than .5; ideally these bounds could be set as variables. I would also like the number of rows and columns generated to be set as a variable. However, the constraint that all columns should sum to 1 should be fixed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dirichlet distribution from the `MCMCpack` library.  All alpha parameters should be set to 1.

```
library(MCMCpack)
mat=rdirichlet(n_columns,rep(1,n_rows))
mat=t(mat) #rotated because you want columns to add to one, not the rows
```

I'm not sure how you go about setting limits on how big elements can be (like the 0.5 you set above), but if computation time isn't imperative, I would just throw away any columns that have too large of elements.  All you'd need to do is run the code

```
mat=mat[,which(apply(mat,2,max)<0.5)]
```

To get rid of the unwanted columns.

Comment: that was very fast for a not so easy question.

Comment: I recently used the Dirichlet distribution for my homework problems, and it is often used for modeling probabilities of categorical probability densities. Its property of all x_i summing to 1 is what makes it useful, and the (non-normalized) probability density is 

    prod(x^(alpha-1))

Hence, when all alphas are 1, it is simply a constrained uniform distribution.

Comment: May I ask what you are studying, as it may be useful for further research?

Comment: I'm a master's student in statistics.  The Dirichlet was used in both my categorical data analysis class and a mathematical statistics class.  I do a lot of R programming in addition to what's required, though, so that's allowed me to program more quickly.

Comment: While I accepted this answer, there would be value if someone could come up with a solution that can return a deterministic number of columns when setting an upper bound on elements.